# How to profile / identify the slow steps in a tight processing loop?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, profiling

I have some proprietary image processing code.  It walks over an image and computes some statistics on the image.  An example of the kind of code I'm talking about, can be seen below, although this is **not** the algorithm that needs optimizing.

My question is, what tools exist for profiling these kinds of tight loops, to determine where things are slow?  Sleepy, Windows Performance Analyzer all focus more at identifying which methods/functions are slow.  I already know what function is slow, I just need to figure out how to optimize it.

```
void BGR2YUV(IplImage* bgrImg, IplImage* yuvImg)
{
    const int height    = bgrImg->height;
    const int width     = bgrImg->width;
    const int step      = bgrImg->widthStep;
    const int channels  = bgrImg->nChannels;

    assert(channels == 3);
    assert(bgrImg->height == yuvImg->height);
    assert(bgrImg->width == yuvImg->width);
    // for reasons that are not clear to me, these are not the same.
    // Code below has been modified to reflect this fact, but if they 
    // could be the same, the code below gets sped up a bit.
//  assert(bgrImg->widthStep == yuvImg->widthStep);
    assert(bgrImg->nChannels == yuvImg->nChannels);

    const uchar* bgr = (uchar*) bgrImg->imageData;
          uchar* yuv = (uchar*) yuvImg->imageData;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
        {
            const int ixBGR = i*step+j*channels;
            const int b = (int) bgr[ixBGR+0];
            const int g = (int) bgr[ixBGR+1];
            const int r = (int) bgr[ixBGR+2];

            const int y = (int) (0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b);
            const double di = 0.596 * r - 0.274 * g - 0.322 * b;
            const double dq = 0.211 * r - 0.523 * g + 0.312 * b;
            // Do some shifting and trimming to get i & q to fit into uchars.
            const int iv = (int) (128 + max(-128.0, min(127.0, di)));
            const int q = (int) (128 + max(-128.0, min(127.0, dq)));

            const int ixYUV = i*yuvImg->widthStep + j*channels;
            yuv[ixYUV+0] = (uchar)y;
            yuv[ixYUV+1] = (uchar)iv;
            yuv[ixYUV+2] = (uchar)q;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a decent sampling profiler. If you're stuck with Windows then probably the best bet would be Intel's VTune.

Comment: If you know which function is consuming lots of time, disassemble it and look carefully at the instructions generated in the inner loop

Comment: Visual Studio does not have the best-in-class profiler, but it does a decent job. Google for `visual studio profiler`. Or google your_favourite_os profiler

Comment: Specifically, in Visual Studio 2010: -> Analyze -> Launch Performance Wizard -> answer questions, launch app -> "Show Hot Lines."  @Shambool's answer is the right "meta" answer, but to identify specific implementation bottlenecks, this does what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cant share the code I have some general suggestions. First remember profilers tell you what part of code is taking more time and more advanced ones can suggest some modifications to improve the speed. But in general, algorithmic optimizations gain much more speed up than tweaking the code. For the sample code you're sharing, if you google efficient or fast RGB to YUV conversion you will find loads of methods (from using lookup tables to SSE2 and GPU utilization) that improve the speed drastically and I'm sure none of the profilers can suggest any of them.

So once you know what part of the method is slow, you can follow these two steps:

1. **algorithmic optimization**: understand what the algorithm is doing and try to come up with a more optimized algorithm. Google is your friend, it's likely someone already has thought optimizing that algorithm and has shared the idea/code with the world. Through, often you should consider the constraints you have. For example, the simplest but the most effective image processing method to speed up the code is to reduce the size of image to the smallest possible. A good rule of thumb is to question every single assumption made in the code/algorithm. e.g., is processing a 800x600 image necessary? or could reduce the size to 320x240 without compromising accuracy? Is processing a three channel image is necessary? or the same could be achieved with a grayscale image? I think you get the idea.
2. **implementation optimization**: some advanced profiling tools can suggest how to tweak the code you can try to find one that's affordable. Some might not agree, but I don't think it's necessary to use such tools. Often image processing exact values are not necessary, a rough approximation of the filter response perhaps by integers, for example, can be used instead of exact computation by double floats. SIMD instructions and more recently GPUs have been shown perfectly suitable for optimizing image processing methods. You should consider that if it's possible to do so. You could always to google how to optimize loops or some specific operations. And after all you can do is done one possibility is to break down your code into smaller logical pieces and change it such that the algorithm or method is not revealed by sharing the pieces. Then you can share each piece on SO and ask other's opinion on how to optimize it.

Comment: Those are all good points.  What I found optimizing the above algorithm, is that just changing from float to integer arithmetic sped things up by an order of magnitude.  SSE2 and similar are options that we'll be investigating.  Have you used SSE2?  What kinds of speed improvements have you seen?  I have found it difficult to get any sort of "feel" for what improvements I can expect.

Comment: The speed up by using SSE2 is very close to what it promises. If you manage to rewrite the code to use SSE2 in an efficient way, and process four operands with one instruction that part of your code will be four times faster.